# I can't make JQuery Cycle work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a website for an internship program and its been going smooth for the basics. However, I can't seem to make JQuery Cycle to work. I checked to see if the JQuery is updated and  if the code is ok. It works fine except the JQuery Cycle function. Here is the code without CSS.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>

            <img src="Seal.png"> 

            <h1> S.T.E.M-READY </h1>

            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href ="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="AboutUS.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="Alumni.html">Alumni</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="Sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="Apply.html">Apply</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </head>



        <div class="pics">
            <img src="Picture1.jpg" width="350" height="300"/>
            <img src="Picture2.jpg" width="350" height="300"/>
            <img src="Picture3.jpg" width="350" height="300"/>
            <img src="Picture4.jpg" width="350" height="300"/>
            <img src="Picture5.jpg" width="350" height="300"/>
        </div>



    </body> 

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.pics').cycle(
        { 
            fx: 'fade', 
            speed: 300, 
            timeout: 1000, 
            next: '#s3', 
            pause: 1 
            });


        });
    </script>`

</html>
```

Comment: please validate your html in w3c validator.

Comment: seems like working http://jsfiddle.net/2xBk6/ ?

Comment: Having the `<head>` inside the `<body>` probably isn't helping

Comment: your code works well when correct the html tags http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/rpJ8L/

Comment: I will try to fix my html and see if it works